# Generate a Random Number That Evenly Divides into Another in C#

Tags: c#, .net, random

I am making a quiz that quizzes a user on basic arithmetic skills. The problem I have is that I don't want to be able to generate a division question that allows real numbers. I want all answers to have integer answers.

How can I randomly generate a number between p and q that evenly divides into n?

Comment: Do it other way around: generate two numbers and just use their multiplication as desired number.

Comment: Didn't even think of that. Thought I'd have to build a lookup table or something. How can I account for the fact the numerator will be much larger than the other generated operands?

Comment: Well, if you need a number between p and q, you can generate first number randomly and for the second one generarate something in range [p / first number; q / first number]

Comment: @CanadaIT does any of the answers here match with what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to generate two integers `a and n`, and then return `a` and `c = a * n`. The answerer should guess what is `n` and **beware of division by zero**!

Something like this will do:

```
public KeyValuePair<int, int> GenerateIntDivisibleNoPair(int p, int q) {
    if (p <= 0 || q <= 0 || q <= p)
        throw Exception(); //for simplification of idea
    Random rand = new Random();
    int a = rand.Next(p, q + 1); //cannot be zero! note: maxValue put as q + 1 to include q
    int n = rand.Next(p, q + 1); //cannot be zero! note: maxValue put as q + 1 to include q
    return new KeyValuePair<int, int>(a, a * n);
}
```

You use it like this:

```
KeyValuePair<int, int> val = GenerateIntDivisibleNoPair(1, 101);
Console.WriteLine("What is " + val.Value.ToString() + " divide by " + val.Key.ToString() + "?");
```

Comment: you could also do rand.Next(1,100) instead of adding one to generated number

Comment: @Viru ah, yes. Certainly. I want 100 to be inclusive. That's why I put that. But you are right. we can actually put `rand.Next(1, 101);` :)

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins (1) "This solution ignores that the generated number needs to be in the range p and q. On top of that it asserts that both p and n are limited to between 1 and 100, which isn't what the question asked for" you are right, perhaps I should update my answer. but this (2) "I'm guessing that it was Ian that marked down my correct and detailed solution down by one"  you are wrong, I didn't do anything.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins to prove that I will now upvote you answer for a while and then unupvote again...

Comment: This solution ignores that the generated number needs to be in the range p and q. On top of that it asserts that both p and n are limited to being between 1 and 100, which isn't what the question asked for. ;)

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins that's ok. :) I can understand the feeling of someone who answer well but downvoted.. It is not your fault.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a Random declared somewhere with global access:

```
public static Random Rnd { get; set; }
```

Then when you want a number that divides by another you keep generating a number until you get one that divides by your Divisor:

```
if(Rnd == null)
{
    Rnd = new Random();

}

int Min = p; //Can be any number

int Max = q; //Can be any number

if(Min > Max) //Assert that Min is lower than Max
{
    int Temp = Max;
    Max = Min;
    Min = Temp;

}

int Divisor = n; //Can be any number

int NextRandom = Rnd.Next(Min, Max + 1); //Add 1 to Max, because Next always returns one less than the value of Max.

while(NextRandom % Divisor != 0)
{
    NextRandom = Rnd.Next(Min, Max + 1); //Add 1 to Max, because Next always returns one less than the value of Max.

}
```

The check uses the modulus function %. This function gives you the remainder of an integer divide.

This means that if the NextRandom % Divisor is 0, then the Divisor divides evenly into NextRandom.

This can be turned into a method like so:

```
public static int GetRandomMultiple(int divisor, int min, int max)
{
    if (Rnd == null)
    {
         Rnd = new Random();

    }

    if(min > max) //Assert that min is lower than max
    {
        int Temp = max;
        max = min;
        min = Temp;

    }

    int NextRandom = Rnd.Next(min, max + 1); //Add 1 to Max, because Next always returns one less than the value of Max.

    while (NextRandom % divisor != 0)
    {
        NextRandom = Rnd.Next(min, max + 1); //Add 1 to Max, because Next always returns one less than the value of Max.

    }

    return NextRandom;

}
```

Then you can call it with the variables you mentioned like so:

```
int Number = GetRandomMultiple(n, p, q);
```

***Note: I add one to the value of Max because of the 'Next' method. I think it's a bug in .Net. The value of Max is never returned, only Min..Max - 1. Adding one compensates for this.***

Comment: no it's not a bug - it's the _The exclusive upper bound_ with focus on exclusive https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry fubo, but I still consider it a bug, because the common understanding for a range is that the values are both inclusive. At the very least both should either be inclusive or exclusive. Mixing the two just confuses things, especially as a default action for a high level api like .Net.

Comment: but it's a documented behaviour. i think the reason is the implementation http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/random.cs.html

Comment: Yes, the behaviour is documented, but should it work this way? I can't think of a single reason to support why it would have been designed to work this way and I've already explained why I think the range should be inclusive.